# IPhone app shows previous state when opening

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have  very weird problem. My app works cool on `simulator` but when installed on `iphone` it shows strange behavior

Suppose i was at `settings` page then I closed the app using home button. And then I start the app again after quite a while and I will always first get the settings page for one second and then the main loading screen. This happens for every other page even its not the settings `ViewController`

What is wrong?

Best Regards
Umar

Comment: Do you have any splash image assigned to your app?

Comment: yes , that's the loading screen actually.it doesn't actually load just sa loading bar image act as splash image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard behavior, UI restoration. Your iOS apps picks up execution right where you left.
This means: if the app is pushed to background, a screenshot is taken. Coming back to the app, this screenshot will be shown and meanwhile your UI gets prepared.
If you have code in your app in `applicationDidBecomeActive:` or `applicationWillEnterForeground:` (see here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and that will immediately reconfigure the UI, you get the behavior described.
You can turn OFF UI restoration and have your app really quit instead of pushing it to background by changing a key in the info.plist: `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend`

Comment: can you guide me how to do this?

Comment: This is basic iOS design knowledge. You should go through the programming guides (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH1-SW1) or maybe buy a book about CocoaTouch/iOS development. There are also plenty of iOS tutorials on the web, just google.